# $RL=L$ Progress Since 2006

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, pseudorandomness

Reingold, Trevisan, and Vadhan's breakthrough 2006 paper (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1132583) reduced the problem of showing $RL=L$ to producing pseudorandom walks on regular digraphs that are not consistently labeled.

Has any further progress on this problem been made since then?

Comment: Another step towards closing the gap between s-t connectivity in regular digraphs with arbitrary labelling (L) and poly-mixing s-t connectivity (RL-complete) has been done by [Kai-Min Chung, Omer Reingold, and Salil Vadhan. 2011. S-T connectivity on digraphs with a known stationary distribution.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1978785&CFID=390405357&CFTOKEN=46059609). They introduce an intermediate problem in L called "known-stationary s-t connectivity", but - to be honest - I (absolutely) don't understand much of that nice stuff :-) :-)

Comment: There has been a fair amount of work on constant-space derandomization. Some examples:
[BRRY10](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/035/),
[BV10](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.173.1241),
[KNP11](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/113/),
[De11](http://www.math.ias.edu/~anindya/full-reg.pdf),
[RSV13](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3004).
I, for one, like to believe that this represents some sort of progress towards RL=L.

Answer (score 11):

- One line of work has shown how to *improve the analysis of the classic [INW PRG](https://doi.org/10.1145/195058.195190)* for the special cases of fooling regular and permutation branching programs. The seed length is only $\widetilde{O}(\log n)$ or $O(\log n)$ in some cases. [[LRTV09]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03685-9_46) [[BV10]](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Ebrody/papers/CoinProblemFullVersion.pdf) [[De11]](https://doi.org/10.1109/CCC.2011.23) [[KNP11]](https://doi.org/10.1145/1993636.1993672) [[Ste12]](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2012/083/) [[BRRY14]](https://doi.org/10.1137/120875673) [[HPV21]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.ITCS.2021.7)
- Another line of work has developed a PRG framework based on *iterated pseudorandom restrictions.* This framework has been used to fool various classes of functions that can be computed by "arbitrary-order" read-once branching programs. Again, in some cases the seed length is $\widetilde{O}(\log n)$ or even $O(\log n)$. [[GMRTV12]](https://doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2012.77) [[GLS12]](https://doi.org/10.1109/CCC.2012.37) [[RSV13]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-40328-6_45) [[CSV15]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04675) [[SVW17]](https://doi.org/10.4086/toc.2017.v013a012) [[CHRT18]](https://doi.org/10.1145/3188745.3188800) [[HLV18]](https://doi.org/10.1137/17M1129088) [[FK18]](https://doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2018.00093) [[MRT19]](https://doi.org/10.1145/3313276.3316319) [[DHH19]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.CCC.2019.16) [[Lee19]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.CCC.2019.7) [[LV20]](http://doi.org/10.4086/toc.2020.v016a007) [[DHH20]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.CCC.2020.6) [[DMRTV21]](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2021/018/)
- The paper referenced in the original question is part of a line of work that *uses spectral techniques to design graph algorithms* for space-bounded derandomization. That line of work, which most famously includes [Reingold's algorithm for undirected connectivity](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1391289.1391291), has continued. Recently the focus has been on simulating random walks of length much less than the mixing time of the graph. [[CRV11]](https://doi.org/10.1145/1978782.1978785) [[MRSV17]](https://doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2017.79) [[MRSV19]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.APPROX-RANDOM.2019.42) [[AKMPSV20]](https://doi.org/10.1109/FOCS46700.2020.00123)
- Finally, there is a line of work designing improved *low-error generalized PRGs* for polynomial-width read-once branching programs. By "generalized PRGs," I am referring to (a) hitting set generators and (b) weighted pseudorandom generators, aka pseudorandom pseudodistribution generators. [[BCG20]](https://doi.org/10.1137/18M1197734) [[HZ20]](https://doi.org/10.1137/19M1268707) [[CL20]](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.CCC.2020.25) [[CDRSTS21]](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2021/020/) [[PV21]](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2021/019/) [[Hoz21]](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2021/048/)

Please forgive me for inevitably omitting many excellent papers from this summary, including lots of work that doesn't fit neatly into the four themes above.

See also: Reingold's two-part presentation ["Recent Developments Related to RL vs. L"](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/events/details?eID=1192) at the DIMACS Day of Complexity Tutorials prior to CCC 2019, and the STOC 2020 workshop ["Derandomizing Space-Bounded Computation"](https://sites.google.com/site/avishaytal/derandomizing-space-bounded-computation) organized by Meka, Tal, and Zuckerman.